# Dynamically child is added in android expandable listview

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

i have to use below code...i have to get child value for first group...but here i have to click second group means it is not expanded and sametime the app is force closed.so please help me..how is put the different child value for different parents....please give me sample code for this...

```
private List createGroupList() {

    Log.d(TAG, "Adding groups values");
    List<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> statusMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    statusMap.put(GroupID, "OrderInfo");
    list.add(statusMap);
    HashMap<String, String> usersMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    usersMap.put(GroupID, "CustomerInfo");
    list.add(usersMap);
    Log.d(TAG, "Adding groups values successfull");
    return list;
}


 private List createChildList() {

    ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
    for( int i = 0 ; i < 1 ; ++i ) { // this -15 is the number of groups(Here it's fifteen)
      /* each group need each HashMap-Here for each group we have 3 subgroups */
      ArrayList secList = new ArrayList();
      for( int n = 0 ; n < 1 ; n++ ) {
        HashMap child = new HashMap();


       String s= getIntent().getStringExtra("payment_method");
       String s1= getIntent().getStringExtra("total");
       String s2= getIntent().getStringExtra("firstname");
       String s3= getIntent().getStringExtra("lastname");

     child.put( "KEY_ARTIST", s);
     child.put( "KEY_DURATION", s1);
     child.put( "KEY_FNAME", s2);
     child.put( "KEY_LNAME", s3);

        secList.add( child);
      }
     result.add( secList );
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @krishnaveni.. it you got solved then you should post your solution as answer and accept it so it will be helpful in future for someone. Thanks hope you got me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code:

```
final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> headerData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    final HashMap<String, String> group1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    group1.put(NAME, "OrderInfo");
    headerData.add( group1 );

    final HashMap<String, String> group2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    group2.put(NAME, "CustomerInfo");
    headerData.add( group2);

    final ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>> childData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>>();

    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> group1data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    childData.add(group1data);

    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> group2data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    childData.add(group2data);
```

the above code is useful for me....so try dis above code.